# Why adding a fulltext index in a MySql table would fail?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, indexing, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a ruby on rails project which is using a mysql database.

I try to add one fulltext index upon one of my model for 2 attributes (name & body).

I did the following migration:

```
  def change
    add_index :my_model_table_name, [:name], type: :fulltext
    add_index :my_model_table_name, [:body], type: :fulltext
    add_index :my_model_table_name, [:name, :body], type: :fulltext
  end
```

However, the third index did not go through. The error was:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry ‘NULL-NULL’ for key ‘my_model_table_name.index_my_model_on_name_and_body’
```

After checking my values, I do not have any row where name or body is null (nor empty string).

I decided to run the command using MySql console directly.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE my_model_table_name ADD FULLTEXT INDEX my_index_name (name, body);
```

The result was the same.

However, after running the same command multiple times. It worked: my index has successfully been added into my table.

What am I missing?

Here is my table schema:

[image: desc my_table]

Thank you for your help.

Versions:

- MySql 8.0.28
- Ruby 2.7.6
- Rails 6.1.7.1

Comment: I've seen this where your table is lightly corrupted and has data in it which isn't permitted. You may need to fix this manually, then `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to rebuild it and be sure this is repaired.

Comment: Do a SHOW CREATE TABLE on that table so we can see the schema.

Comment: I just added the table schema.
How do you know which row is lightly corrupted?

Comment: *I just added the table schema.* No. "Table schema" == "Complete output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`".

Comment: Your table definition shows that name and body can be null, try changing them to not null and then try adding the index again.

Comment: i have same issue its seems its mysql bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109242